# Получение значений из узлов NodeList и добавление их в List<String> через лямбда выражения

Tags: java-8, лямбда-выражение

Возможно ли переписать данное выражение со Stream API.

```java
    private static List<String> getListValueOfNodes(NodeList nodeList) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node item = nodeList.item(i);
            String nodeValue = item.getNodeValue();

            list.add(nodeValue);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return IntStream.range(0, nodeList.getLength())
                .mapToObj(nodeList::item)
                .map(Node::getNodeValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```